# javascript click event isn't working on link inside contenteditable div in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios6

HTML:

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
Some text <a href="/">Link</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#content").find('a').click(function(){
    alert('a clicked');
});
```

Problem: alert isn't called. It seems that click event isn't called

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bFtbV/

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info here, unless you didn't override the default behavior of the link.
If that is the case with this code it should work:

```
$("#content").find('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('a clicked');
    return false;
});
```

If not:

- The problem is somewhere else like js error preventing the script
  to execute? What your browser console says?
- Is the link clickable at all, clean the script and put href
  reference, some address and test it.
- There might be 3th option you are using framework that already
  overrode the native click event.

Have you tested it on a pc or mac? iOS isn't the best place to debug!
With iOS6 it's even harder unless you have mac with Lion OS X.

Test and give us feedback

Comment: Tried here http://jsfiddle.net/bFtbV/3/ but no avail. Safari on Mac works good but iOS not

Comment: Click event is supported by mobile safari. There must be an error before script is executed. Is that all the code you are testing with?

Comment: It seems click isn't fired because of contenteditable=true. If it is false, click works fine

Comment: So you can't handle click events in a contenteditable element at all?  I'm having issues with Internet Explorer but not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the a tag directly in the selector:

```
$("#content a").click(function(){
    alert('a clicked');
});
```